# Working directory error while parsing

Tags: r, xml-parsing, rvest

I'd like to apologise in advance for the lack of a reproducible example. The data I'm using my script on are not live right now and are confidential in addition.

I wanted to make a script which can find all links on a certain page. The script works as following:

```
* find homepage html to start with
* find all urls on this homepage 
* open these urls with Selenium
* save the html of each page in a list
* repeat this (find urls, open urls, save html)
```

The workhorse of this script is the following function:

```
function(listofhtmls) {
  urls <- lapply(listofhtmls, scrape)
  urls <- lapply(urls, clean)
  urls <- unlist(urls)
  urls <- urls[-which(duplicated(urls))]
  urls <- paste("base_url", urls, sep = "")
  html <- lapply(urls, savesource)
  result <- list(html, urls)
  return(result) }
```

Urls are scraped, cleaned (I don't need all urls) and duplicated urls are removed.

All of this works fine for most pages but sometimes I get a strange error while using this function:

```
Error: '' does not exist in current working directory.
Called from: check_path(path)
```

I don't see any link between the working directory and the parsing that's going on. I'd like to resolve this error as it's kinda blocking the rest of my script at the moment. Thanks in advance and once again excuses for not using a reproducible example.